# ITransferSource::MoveItem moves folder without content

Tags: windows, shell, drag-and-drop, explorer

I develop NSE. It has files and folders. Component with interface ITransferSource is implemented. During Drag&Drop (MOVE) method ITransferSource::MoveItem() is called. MOVE must be implemented as COPY&DELETE, so I return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_NOT_SAME_DEVICE) for files and E_NOINTERFACE. Files are moved successfully, but folders are not. Here is the sequence of calls which explorer performs:

1. ITransferSource::MoveItem() - I return E_NOINTERFACE
2. ITransferSource::OpenItem() - I return resource for reading for
   folder.
3. IShellItemResources::GetSize() - I return 0 for folder
4. IShellItemResources::GetAttributes() - I return FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY IShellFolder::EnumObjects() - explorer goes
   into folder and enums children items. For each item it is checked if
   item is folder.
5. ITransferSource::RemoveItem() - folder is removed

As you can see folder is copied and deleted but childer items are skipped. Explorer knows that they exists (via EnumObjects) but doesn't copy them.

Comment: Drag&Drop COPY works fine. MOVE - not. The problems seems to be in order. When items are copied they have processing order: parent folder is first, child file is last. When items are moved copying order isn't deletion order. Copy: parent folder is first, child file is last. Delete: child file is first, parent folder is last.

Comment: OK, here is the answer. When MoveItem returns HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_NOT_SAME_DEVICE) move operation is replaced on copy & delete. When item is copied RemoveItem is called and you pay attention to dwFlags argument. It has TSF_MOVE_AS_COPY_DELETE bit set. Do not delete item in this case. Other item will be copied, and other, and other... When all items are copied RemoveItem is called again but without flag TSF_MOVE_AS_COPY_DELETE. OK, you can delete folder and files now. Result code COPYENGINE_S_DONT_PROCESS_CHILDREN can be usefull too.